# How to use multi-key words in the MSSQL (ANSISQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, ansi-sql

I know how to do in Oracle as following example code, however how can i do in ANSI SQL like MSSQL to do the same script, please help me to handle this question.

PS: this script is for multi-key words(PNO,CASENO,SCRN,IRBCODE,ITEMCODE,MMHCODE,ROWNO)

For example

```
SELECT * FROM TEST 
WHERE (PNO,CASENO,SCRN,IRBCODE,ITEMCODE,MMHCODE,ROWNO) 
IN 
( 
    SELECT PNO,CASENO,SCRN,IRBCODE,ITEMCODE,MMHCODE,ROWNO FROM TEST 
    WHERE CASENO > 0 AND TO_CHAR(SCRN,'YYYY') = '2017' 
)
```

Please let me know if my question isn't very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gordon Linoff had given you very great example , I just change a little bit ,hopefully it can help you

```
SELECT t.*
FROM irbvisit t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM irbvisit t2
              WHERE t2.CASENO > 0 AND
                  convert(varchar(4), SCRN, 126)='2017' and 
                    t2.PNO = t.PNO AND
                    t2.CASENO = t.CASENO AND
                    t2.SCRN = t.SCRN AND
                    t2.IRBCODE = t.IRBCODE AND
                    t2.ITEMCODE = t.ITEMCODE AND
                    t2.MMHCODE = t.MMHCODE AND
                    t2.ROWNO = t.ROWNO
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` in any database:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TEST t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TEST t2
              WHERE t2.CASENO > 0 AND
                    YEAR(t2.SCRN) = 2017 AND
                    t2.PNO = t.PNO AND
                    t2.CASENO = t.CASE_NO AND
                    t2.SCRN = t.SCRN AND
                    t2.IRBCODE = t.IRBCODE AND
                    t2.ITEMCODE = t.ITEMCODE AND
                    t2.MMHCODE = t.MMHCODE AND
                    t2.ROWNO = t.ROWNO
             );
```

Given that you are testing for being in the same table, I think the following does the same thing:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TEST t
WHERE t.CASENO > 0 AND TO_CHAR(t.SCRN, 'YYYY') = '2017';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response soon , but my case is for T-SQL not for Oracle ,hopefully you can give me ANSI -SQL example thanks again

Comment: @WillieCheng . . . The only Oracle'ish syntax was the `TO_CHAR()`.  That is easily replaced with `YEAR()` or a similar function.